# Do I keep the 'HEAD' 'BODY' tags when loading AJAX content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was thinking, when I want to load AJAX content that has its own scripts and CSS to be loaded and executed, how do I format that content to be loaded?

Do I still keep the `<head>` and `<body>` tags in the document or does it not matter anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy is to load partial pages, just the content that is needed and to use [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or a similar method of making sure your javascript events work for the additional content. As was stated before you really want to only have one set of scripts and probably one css file for everything. A lot of frameworks provide the ability to load these partial pages easily, but I'm not sure what your stack is.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* matter.  You shouldn't have more than one `<head>` and `<body>`.

It sounds like you'd be better off using an `<iframe>` instead.  It will prevent CSS and JS conflicts as well.